# Form submission with Ant Design' Select

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm currently trying to submit a form from the **Ant Design's** select. I've managed to keep the dropdown open and I have an input inside a form but when I hit enter the form doesn't submit and that happened after I used the **dropdownRender**.

**The dropdown looks like this **

[image]

**What I've done**

```
const createorSelect = ()
 =>{

const handleFormSubmit = (values: { newAccount: string }): void => {
    const { newAccount } = values;
    children.push({ id: children.length + 1, value: newAccount });
    console.log('form submitted...');
  };

  const newAccBtn = (
    <div>
      {showInput ? (
        <Form onFinish={handleFormSubmit}>
          <Form.Item name="newAccount">
            <Input className="new-acc-input" placeholder="Create account..." name="newAccount" />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      ) : (
        <p className="new-acc-btn" onClick={handleOptionClick}>
          <span>Add acount</span>
          <span>
            <img src={profile} alt="New acc" />
          </span>
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Select
      className="selector"
      allowClear={false}
      showSearch
      placeholder="Select..."
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      dropdownRender={(menu) => (
        <>
          {showAddAccount && newAccBtn}
          {menu}
        </>
      )}
    >
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
};
}
```

I want to add the new item to the options list as seen in the dropdown. But the form isn't submitted, hence the new item not being added to the list. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you render Form inside the AccBtn?

Comment: did you see this example from antd docs? https://codesandbox.io/s/j5mr2 I hope its useful for you if it not tell me to solve your problem with open state of drop down

Comment: @HDM91, thanks for your suggestion. It worked!  My initial approach probably behaves differently when the **dropdownRende*r* is used.